# Show list of node titles from a certain taxonomy term

Tags: database

```
<?php
    $result = db_query("SELECT {node}.title, {node}.nid FROM {node} INNER JOIN {term_node} ON {node}.nid = {term_node}.nid WHERE {term_node}.tid = %d ORDER by {node}.title ASC LIMIT %d, %d", 5, 0, 30);
    while ($node = db_fetch_object($result)) {
        $nodes[] = l($node->title, 'node/'.$node->nid);
    }
    foreach($nodes as $list) {
        print $list.'<br />';
    }
?>
```

I want to print node titles from a certain taxonomy term inside a node.
it doesn't prints anything, and print_r($nodes) shows nothing. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: small suggestion... does db_affected_rows() give you a count?? also have you tried executing the query directly to check the results??

Comment: tried if (db_affected_rows() > 0 ) { print 'it does'; } → returns nothing either.

Comment: @optimusprime619 The implementation of `db_affected_rows()` calls the corresponding `*_affected_rows` function of the PHP extension. From theses functions, only [mysqli_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/mysqli.affected-rows) works with SELECT statements. Neither [mysql_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/mysql_affected_rows), nor [pg_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/pg_affected_rows) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose table names in curly braces `{}` everywhere they appear, not just in the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses. So the correct query would be

```
SELECT {node}.title, {node}.nid
FROM {node}
INNER JOIN {term_node} ON {node}.nid = {term_node}.nid
WHERE {term_node}.tid = %d
ORDER by {node}.title ASC
```

You can also use table aliases instead.

If you use table prefixes, your query should have resulted in an error. Turn on PHP's error reporting if you did not see any error message.

If you do not use table prefixes, then the reason is, that the database query simply returns an empty result set (i.e. no node is tagged with the taxonomy term that has `5` as `tid`).

Also note the following:

- In the line

  ```
  $nodes = l($node->title, 'node/'.$node->nid);
  ```

  you overwrite the previous result and thus the previous result is lost. But if a result would actually exist, at least the *last* result should be printed. Nevertheless, use

  ```
  $nodes[] = l($node->title, 'node/'.$node->nid);
  ```

  to be able to use *all* results.
- You pass three arguments to the query (`5`, `0`, `30`), but the query only has one parameter (`term_node.tid = %d`). Are you sure that `5` is the `tid` you are interested in? The other arguments are ignored.
- If you create a new revision of a node that has the requested term and then remove the term from the new revision, the node will still appear in the result set. Join on the `vid` of the node instead of on the `nid` to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. It is from documentation - "You have to enclose table names in curly braces {}" ? Then you said: "Are you sure that 5 is the tid you are interested in? The other arguments are ignored." - Yes, i'm sure. Other 2 arguments goes for LIMIT 0, 30.

Comment: I just found that tid != term id :O I just went to the phpmyadmin an rechecked {term_node} and all my nodes that associated with a term id 5 had tid = 148... What the hell is that..